# Changing a div's style when clicked, and changing it back when another div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have a number of divs with the class `trashitem` within a .hta file. Upon clicking a particular div I need to change its border to 3px and red. When a different div is selected, I need the original div to revert back to its original style (1px black border) and **ALSO** change this second div's border to 3px red.

Basically only one div can be red at a time.

Pure JavaScript is preferred over jQuery please. I'm assuming I need to apply a class to the clicked div, and remove it from this class if another div is chosen, while adding this second div to the class or something?

All the divs have the class `trashitem` but they each are referencing a unique function onclick, see below:

```
<div class="trashitem" onclick="Writedata13()">
   <div class="photobox">
      <img src="http://www.fakeImage.JPG">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="trashitem" onclick="Writedata14()">
   <div class="photobox">
      <img src="http://www.fakeImage.JPG">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="trashitem" onclick="Writedata15()">
   <div class="photobox">
      <img src="http://www.fakeImage.JPG">
   </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATED CODE**

---

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script language="javascript">
function Writedata14(event)
{
 var a = event.target;  
 a.style.cssText = 'width:330px;height:10px;background-color:black';  
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="trashitem" onclick="Writedata14()">
    <div class="photobox">
        <img src="http://www.fakeImage.JPG">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="trashitem" onclick="Writedata15()">
    <div class="photobox">
        <img src="http://www.fakeImage.JPG">
     </div>
</div>
```

Link to [Codepen demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVvvME](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVvvME).

Comment: *"I'm assuming I need to apply a class to the clicked div, and remove it from this class if another div is chosen, while adding this second div to the class or something?"* - Yes, indeed.

Comment: I've searched for like 1.5 hours on StackOverflow and all the solutions are jQuery. Can you please help me out? I don't know how to proceed. Anything besides making me feel stupid is welcome. Thank you

Comment: What do all the functions do? Given the naming it seems as if they're likely to do the same thing, but with only minor differences? Incidentally, please don't remove sample code from your question; a link to an external demo is appreciated as a bonus, but the code *must* be in the question itself.

Comment: I'll be sure to not remove code in the future, sorry about that. You're right about the functions doing very similar things, the only difference being that  for example, function Writedata8() will have this:     s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('mls_id8').value);
s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('marker_id8').value);     whereas Writedata9() will have mls_id9 and marker_id9 respectively. There's likely a much cleaner way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid to use javascript inline, that is deprecate.

Trying using this:

```js
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var myitem = document.querySelectorAll(".trashitem");
    for(h=0; h<myitem.length; h++){
        myitem[h].addEventListener("click",function(e){
            var myitem = document.querySelectorAll(".trashitem");

            for(h=0; h<myitem.length; h++){
                myitem[h].classList.remove("bordered");
            }

            this.classList.add("bordered");

        });
    }
});
```

```css
.bordered{
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.trashitem{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.trashitem img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Click the box

<div class="trashitem">
    <div class="photobox">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="trashitem" >
    <div class="photobox">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="trashitem" >
    <div class="photobox">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

You can try using `.onclick` like this:

```js
window.onload = function (event) {

    var myitem = document.querySelectorAll(".trashitem");
    for(h=0; h<myitem.length; h++){
        myitem[h].onclick = function(e){
            var myitem = document.querySelectorAll(".trashitem");

            for(h=0; h<myitem.length; h++){
                myitem[h].classList.remove("bordered");
            }

            this.classList.add("bordered");

        };
    }
};
```

```css
.bordered{
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.trashitem{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.trashitem img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Click the box

<div class="trashitem">
    <div class="photobox">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="trashitem" >
    <div class="photobox">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="trashitem" >
    <div class="photobox">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you both, but when I run this code in my .hta file, it says "Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'.

Comment: Here is a link to my full .hta file, it's pretty short. Please help~ http://pastebin.com/MvmcqDUn

Comment: @DavidThomas you are right that was a typo, I updated my answer to fix it and I added a working example.

Comment: I'm using a .hta file remember, so when I run your code it gives error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'.  I'm guessing this is a problem with HTA. Solution? Thank you Yandy

Comment: Your edited solution still contains the text "addEventListener" which is precisely what is causing my error still. I've found a potential solution here, but not sure how to adapt it to my code. Can you help please? http://rubayathasan.com/tutorial/ie8-addeventlistener-alternative-example/

Comment: You've fixed it Yandy with your recent update using querySelectorAll. I also had to add <!DOCTYPE html> to the very top, and add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> in the <head> tag. Thanks for sticking with me, I greatly appreciate your help. Take care :)

Comment: @Hurmle sorry I forget change it, I only change the  `addEventListener`  of  the `click`, I edit my answer to use the old method of loading javascript code and functions `window.onload` by the way `attachEvent` is only for compatibility with IE.

Comment: I see that. My comment just above yours shows how I solved it with your solution. Marked as solved, thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad to help you, I'm just writing my comment when I saw yours :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the element that being  click with

```
 event.target;
```

and you might do something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Writedata13(){
             var a = event.target;  
             a.style.cssText = 'width:330px;height:10px;background-color:black';          
        }
</script>
```

see this to get more information about it
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp

Comment: That seems like a possible solution, thank you. Two questions: When I add your code and then click the div, I get the error: "Unable to get property "style" of undefined or null reference. "Is this referring to the cssText part? 

Secondly, your solution seems like it will change a div's style, but will it change it BACK if another div is clicked afterwards? Thanks Spycomb

Comment: `function Writedata13()` should be declared as `function Writedata13(event)`. Then you will have an event object of which you can get the target element.

Comment: Thanks Golez, but now I get the same error as before but now it's saying "target" is undefined or null. Here is a codepen link, but I need the border to STAY red when clicked, until another div is clicked. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVvvME